# Extra blank lines in reledpar within paragraph

Tags: line-spacing, reledmac, setspace, reledpar

I am formatting a facing-page translation using `reledmac`/`reledpar` and I am seeing occasional (apparently random) extra blank lines in mid-paragraph where there is *no* break in the source text. You can see this in the example at line 15 on the left-hand page and between 12R and 13R on the right-hand page.

[image: Example of extra blank lines]

(edit) This is the output of `\showputput` around the word "Ybor" towards the end of line 12R on the right-hand side.

```
....\EU1/antpoltlt(0)/m/n/10 Ybor,
....\penalty 10000
....\hbox(8.18507+0.0)x10.30273
.....\mathon
.....\hbox(4.55615+0.0786)x10.30273, shifted -3.62892
......\EU1/Junicode(0)/m/n/7 237
.....\mathoff
....\kern -0.00005
....\kern 0.00005
....\glue 2.95622 plus 1.84763 minus 0.78831
....\EU1/antpoltlt(0)/m/n/10 the
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 9.5018
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x312.0
```

There is also a problem in that there is an extra blank line after the first line of every section (on both sides), although this looks like less than one `\baselineskip`.

Before I start stripping everything back to the bare metal for an MWE, has anyone seen this before, or got pointers to where I might start looking?

I am using XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2018.8.15) under Linux Mint 18.3 with reledmac 2016/02/27 v2.8.2 and reledpar 2016/03/06 v2.7.1

Comment: `\showoutput` then the log would show what the space is, (eg parskip or lineskip or baselineskip etc)

Comment: from your image I would guess the superscript citation macros are doing something....

Comment: without MWE, it is difficul to say. But did you try with newest version of reledmac/reledpar. Maybe one bug has ben correct.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about \showoutput. I'll edit this in above. I suspected the superscripts, but I'll check again. Today: try new versions, if that doesn't break other dependencies.

Comment: That superscript on p.271 line 12R is just a plain `\footnote{238}`; removing it fixed the problem, so the error must be in `reledpar` as I don't redefine `\footnote` anywhere, However, updating `reledmac` and `reledpar` to the CTAN latest breaks on other dependencies in `xparse`, so I'll need to find another way round as I don't want to screw with the Ubuntu TL distro.

Comment: normally, reledmac/reledpar deal with plain footnotes. Did you redefine them?

Comment: No, see above: "I don't redefine `\footnote` anywhere". I'll have to start work on a MWE, which will take many days: this was working fine last time I worked on it over a year ago, so something somewhere has updated and broken it. It's just a matter of finding out what.

Comment: I found the answer (below) while constructing the MWE, which is what I was hoping. `setspace` appears to conflict with `reledmac`/`reledpar` in some way. This doesn't solve the other problem of extra space under the first line of text in every `\section`, but that's another post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. The setspace package, which I had been using to compensate for the Junicode typeface having a much smaller set than Antykwa Torunska, was somehow interfering in the footnote mechanism. Remove the package reference and annul the spacing changes, and the bogus lines go away.

I have not found out what it is in setspace.sty that causes this, but it may be a silent conflict in internal macros.

Comment: That might be a very valuable finding. I have once in a while really strange effects of empty lines and I use setspace. I'll test.