# Extra space under first line of text after \section

Tags: sectioning, line-spacing, reledmac

Having fixed [an earlier case of intrusive line-spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452193/extra-blank-lines-in-reledpar-within-paragraph), I now have white-space being added after the first line of a `\section` (*not* after the section title itself, after the first line of text *below it*) when using `reledmac`/`reledpar` to do a facing-page translation. There appears to be more spacing added on the left-hand (source) page than on the right (target), which is weird.

[image: Example of intrusive vertical white-space]

I have made a MWE in [test.tex](http://latex.silmaril.ie/downloads/test.tex) and [celttest.sty](http://latex.silmaril.ie/downloads/celttest.sty) rather thanpost them inline, because the text is quite long (to fill one page). You will need XeLaTeX and the [Junicode](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/junicode) font installed to process it.

I am sure it's something I have overlooked, but I can't see it.

Comment: There is no possible break point after the section title, probably because of the footnotes, so TeX stretches the only glue available, that is, between paragraphs.

Comment: But it isn't stretching *between* paragraphs, It's stretching the space between two lines *within* a paragraph, between lines 1 and 2. That big space on the LH page is just reledpar aligning para #2 on both sides. That is not the space I mean: I mean the space between line 1 and line 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained manytimes both in SE and in the handbook, and in the example, 
YOU MUST NOT add direclty `\section` and related inside `\pstart`...`\pend` structure.

You must use one on the following system
- If you don't want the section be counted in line numbering, add them as optional argument of `\pstart`
- If you want the section be counted in line numbering, use `\elesection` and related in a specific `\pstart…\pend` structure.

Here an example of first use

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{celttest}
\usepackage[irish,latin,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\selectlanguage{irish}
\beginnumbering
\pstart[\subsubsection{foo}]
Bui iarla soim saidhbir a Saxanaib do
          shindrudh, diarba comainm Risderd o Bharbhaicc,
          ⁊ ro búi da iarlacht aigi .i. iarlacht o
          Bharbhuicc ⁊ iarlacht Bocigam, ⁊ dob
          fer saidhbir, sochinelach in t-iarla co n-ilimud gacha
          maithusa\footnote{Perhaps
        rather to be expanded `maithiusa'. Here and in
        `flaithus', below, I have given the abbreviation its
        usual value of `us'.}. ⁊ ro bui ingen
          cruthach, caemhaluind a dingmala aigi .i. Feilis a
          h-ainm-sidhe, ⁊ ni roibhi ina h-aimsir ben dob
          ferr delbh ⁊ denum, modh ⁊
          múnudh, druine ⁊ dethbes, na'n
          ingin-sin. Do cuiredh immorro ardmaigistir dia munud
          annsna h-el\textsl{adhnaibh} sáera,
          ⁊ nir cian iarum disi co mell\uline{adh} a
          maigistir i n-gach ealathain, co tucc in maigistir slat
          a muinti di budhein iarna sharugudh di i n-gach egna a
          cinn a secht\footnote{Here and
        in many other cases where the MS has the sign of the
        numeral, I have regularly expanded these abbreviations
        in my text.} m-bliadhna dec do sinnrud. Co clos
          fon uili domhun a dethclú itir egna ⁊
          ordan ⁊ einech, etir cradhbudh ⁊
          ciunus ⁊ cunnlacht, itir gloine ⁊ gais
          ⁊ glicus, gur bo lán da serc ⁊
          da sírgradh uaisli ⁊ ardmaithi na
          cruinne co comcoitcenn. Ro búi didiu \textit{sdibard} uasal,
          oirbindech ag iarla o Barbuicc an inbuidh sin .i.
          Siccard a ainm sidhe, ⁊ dob fer furtill,
          fírchalma é, co m-buaidh coscuir
          ⁊ commaidhmi i n-gach gním ro bo
          dír do neoch do beth aigi. Gemad uathadh don
          iarla, nír ba h-omhun lais n\uline{er}t sluaigh
          na sochraiti acht co m-beth in t-uasal barun-sin aga
          imcoimét. ⁊ Is é ro bidh ac
          tabhach a císsa ⁊ a chana don iarla,
          ⁊ gidbe do nídh dogra no doible fris im
          cis in iarla, do-beradh san achar ⁊
          innarb\uline{a} asa flaithus fein forra.
\pend\pstart
2]~Ro bui mac a dingmala agan \textit{sdibard}-sin, Gyi a ainm-side,
          ⁊ ro sháraigh na h-uili macu a aimsiri
          ar mét ar maisi ar macantacht, ar nos ar nert ar
          nidechus, ar uaill ar aicnedh ar arachtus, gur ba lan na
          cricha co comlán ⁊ na cennacha
          comfocuiss dia clú ⁊ dia alludh,
          ⁊ gach inadh ina cluineadh Gyi cluithighi
          aonaig ⁊ ibhnis ⁊ oirechtais ar fedh
          ⁊ ar fiarlaidh \sout{crichi}\thinspace:\thinspace crici\footnote{In many cases the marks of aspiration are
        indistinct.} saeruaisli Saxan, {\normalfont\footnotesize[300b]} do freagradh iat ⁊ do-beradh
          buaidh gacha buidhni co barr uil\textsl{e}.
          ⁊ do sharuighedh lucht gacha lamaigh co
          lanaibeil, ⁊ do-beredh almsa ⁊ \sout{othrala}\thinspace:\thinspace otrala\footnote{aspiration
        doubtful} minca dona h-eglasaibh ⁊
          do-beredh 
               {\normalfont\footnotesize\fboxsep1pt\fbox{\vrule height1.75ex width0pt depth.25ex 25}} dercinna ⁊ dethcealta do deb\textsl{l}enaibh Dé, ⁊ ro
          annluiccedh na mairbh gan murmur gan mainnechtnaighi,
          ⁊ do-beredh fisrugudh don lucht no bidh a
          carcair ⁊ a cumgach, ⁊ do nidh na
          h-uili obuir trocuire diar-mol in eglus ina aimsir,
          ⁊ ro bui co daingen, duthrachtach isin creidem
          cathoilic\textsl{d}a. Do rinne iarla o
          Berbuicc sguiger do Gy in tan sin.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\selectlanguage{english}
\markboth{\sffamily Chapter \arabic{section}}{\sffamily }
\beginnumbering
\pstart[\section{}]
1]~{\normalfont\footnotesize[24]}There was an
          exceedingly rich earl in England whose name was Richard
          of Warwick, and he had two earldoms, namely Warwick and
          Buckingham, and a rich and well-born man was the earl
          with an abundance of all good things. He had a comely
          and beautiful daughter worthy of himself, Felice by
          name, and there was not in her time a woman who was
          better in form and figure, in handiwork and knowledge,
          in embroidery and noble manners,\footnote{For this collocation cf. \textit{do thecasc druinechais ⁊ bescna
          doibh}, Marco Polo, \emph{CZ.} 1,
        368.} than that maiden. A great teacher was set
          to instruct her in the gentle arts, and it was not long
          afterwards that she surpassed\footnote{\textit{comelladh}, perhaps
        rather to be expanded \textit{comella}.
        The meaning is also doubtful. I have taken it from
        \textit{millim}.} her master in
          every art, so that the master gave her the rod\footnote{I have noted no exact parallel to
        this use of \textit{slat}.} of his
          instruction after being outstripped by her in every kind
          of knowledge even at the end of her seventeenth year.
          Her fair fame spread throughout all the world for
          knowledge, dignity and honor, for piety, gentleness and
          discretion, for purity, wisdom and prudence, until the
          princes and nobles of the whole earth were filled with
          love and longing for her. Now there was at that time a
          steward, noble and honorable, in the service of the Earl
          of {\normalfont\footnotesize\fboxsep1pt\fbox{\vrule height1.75ex width0pt depth.25ex 106}} Warwick, Siccard by name, and he was a
          strong man and very brave, winning victory and fame in
          every exploit that it was suitable for anyone to engage
          in. If the earl was alone, he had no fear of host or
          army, provided only that noble baron were there to
          defend him. It was he that collected the taxes and
          imposts\footnote{On \textit{cis} and \textit{cain}
        cf. \emph{KZ.} 36, 440 and 37,
        255.} for the earl; and if there were any who
          made complaint or resistance\footnote{The
        translation of \textit{doible} is
        conjectural. It is the same word as \textit{duibhle}, \emph{Battle
          of Magh Rath}, p. 8 (translated
        ‘rage’ by \textbf{O’Donovan})?} to
          him about the taxes of the earl, he would impose upon
          them expulsion and banishment from his realm.
\pend\pstart
2]~That steward had a son worthy of himself, Guy by name;
          and he surpassed all the young men of his time in size,
          beauty and gentleness, in courtesy, strength and
          prowess, in pride, spirit and courage, so that the whole
          country and the neighbouring provinces were full of his
          fame and his praise. And everywhere that Guy heard of
          games at fair or festival or assembly throughout the
          length and breadth of the free and noble English land,
          he entered them and won the victory of every company,
          surpassing all,\footnote{MS. \textit{co barruil}? Dr. \textbf{Meyer} suggested
        the reading in the text.} and defeated the men
          utterly at every kind of feat.\footnote{\textit{lamach} means properly
        ‘hurling’. Cf. \emph{Irische Texte} 4, 274.}
          And he gave alms and frequent offerings\footnote{I have noted no other case of \textit{otrala}, unless it is the same as
        \textit{othrola}, \emph{RC.} 19, 380, which
        Stokes translates ‘prayers’. Should we read \textit{ofrala}?} to the churches, and
          gave {\normalfont\footnotesize[25]} gifts and
          clothing to God’s poor,\footnote{Translation doubtful. Read \textit{deblenaibh}: ‘poor, orphans’?
        But there is also an obscure word \textit{debend} in \emph{O’Mulconry’s Glossary}, \emph{Archiv für celtische
          Lexikographie} i (1898), 271.} and
          buried the dead without murmur and without negligence,
          and visited the people who were in prison and in bonds,
          and performed all the works of mercy which the church
          praised in his time, and he was strong and zealous in
          the Catholic faith. The Earl of Warwick made Guy a
          squire at that time.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}\Pages
This
\end{document}
```

Also look on 
http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/examples/2-titles_in_line_numbering_with_notes.tex

and 
http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/examples/2-titles_not_in_line_numbering.tex

Comment: Thank you -- I missed that entirely, I have no idea why.

Comment: not a problem, it is a classical ask.