# Extra blank line at the end of a paragraph (reledpar / reledmac)

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I am using `reledpar`/`reledmac`to format a 'synopsis' in two columns and I am seeing occasional (apparently random) extra blank lines where there is no blank line/break in the source text. You can see the blank lines in the following example:
[image]

And this is the code of my .tex-file:

```
    \documentclass[oneside, 8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=15mm, right=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{subscript}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\setlength \parindent{0pt}
\rightnoteupfalse
\linenummarginR{left}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\title{Does not matter}
\begin{document}
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering{}

\pstart{}
first ~\\
\skipnumbering{}
\pend{}


\pstart{}
this is a line\pend{}
\pstart{}
another line\pend{}
\pstart{}
line \pend{}
\pstart{}
just a line\pend{}
\pstart{}
and a line\pend{}
\pstart{}
oh it's a line~\\
\skipnumbering{}
\pend{}

\pstart{}
just a line\pend{}
\pstart{}
and a line\pend{}
\pstart{}
oh it's a line~\\
\skipnumbering{}
\pend{}

\pstart{}
just a line\pend{}
\pstart{}
and a line\pend{}
\pstart{}
oh it's a line~\\
\skipnumbering{}
\pend{}




\endnumbering{}
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering{}

\pstart{}
a heading\\
\skipnumbering{}
\pend{}


\pstart{}
\pend{}
\pstart{}
\pend{}
\pstart{}
\pend{}
\pstart{}
\pend{}
\pstart{}
\pend{}
\pstart{}
~\\
\skipnumbering{}
\pend{}


\pstart{}
just a line\pend{}
\pstart{}
and a line\pend{}
\pstart{}
oh it's a line~\\
\skipnumbering{}
\pend{}

\pstart{}
just a line\pend{}
\pstart{}
and a line\pend{}
\pstart{}
~\\
\skipnumbering{}
\pend{}

\endnumbering{}
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns{}
\end{document}
```

I think it might be a similar problem like in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452193/extra-blank-lines-in-reledpar-within-paragraph), but i am not using the setspace package, so i think it's a different problem. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: why do you add {} after `\pend`  and `\pstart`. It is not required, and make the reading of the code harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is cause by your `~\\` on the right side. That makes your side longer. And reledpar make the left side to the same height.

Consider this code, which I simplified from your code:

- no more superfious `{}`
- no more `\skipnumbering`
- 1 put line number every line, to debug
- no class or package not neeeded for a MWE

Here the code

```
\documentclass[oneside, ]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=15mm, right=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\setlength \parindent{0pt}
\rightnoteupfalse
\firstlinenum*{1}
\linenumincrement*{1}
\linenummarginR{left}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\title{Does not matter}
\begin{document}
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
first ~\\
\pend


\pstart
this is a line
\pend
\pstart
another line
\pend
\pstart
line
\pend
\pstart
just a line
\pend
\pstart
and a line here the problem
\pend
\pstart
oh it's a line~
\pend

\pstart
just a line
\pend
\pstart
and a line
\pend
\pstart
oh it's a line
\skipnumbering
\pend

\pstart
just a line
\pend
\pstart
and a line
\pend
\pstart
oh it's a line~\\
\skipnumbering
\pend




\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
a heading\\
\pend


\pstart
\pend
\pstart
\pend
\pstart
\pend
\pstart
\pend
\pstart
\pend
\pstart
~\\
\pend


\pstart
just a line
\pend
\pstart
and a line
\pend
\pstart
oh it's a line~\\
\pend

\pstart
just a line
\pend
\pstart
and a line
\pend
\pstart
~\\
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\end{document}
```

That produce the following output
[image: Output]

Has you can see the extra spaces on right and left side are the same, and correspond to you `~\\` on right side.

If I delete it, all is ok

```
\documentclass[oneside, ]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=15mm, right=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\setlength \parindent{0pt}
\rightnoteupfalse
\firstlinenum*{1}
\linenumincrement*{1}
\linenummarginR{left}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\title{Does not matter}
\begin{document}
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
first ~\\
\pend


\pstart
this is a line
\pend
\pstart
another line
\pend
\pstart
line
\pend
\pstart
just a line
\pend
\pstart
and a line here the problem
\pend
\pstart
oh it's a line
\pend

\pstart
just a line
\pend
\pstart
and a line
\pend
\pstart
oh it's a line
\pend

\pstart
just a line
\pend
\pstart
and a line
\pend
\pstart
oh it's a line
\pend




\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
a heading\\
\pend


\pstart
\pend
\pstart
\pend
\pstart
\pend
\pstart
\pend
\pstart
\pend
\pstart
\pend


\pstart
just a line
\pend
\pstart
and a line
\pend
\pstart
oh it's a line
\pend

\pstart
just a line
\pend
\pstart
and a line
\pend
\pstart
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\end{document}
```

[image]

The question is "why do you add `~\\`? " I am sur you have a good reason to do that, but it is not a good idead due to reledmac internal mecanism. What do you expect? I think we have a solution inside reledmac to your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The intention behind using ~\\ was to create spacing between two paragraphs. But it's probably a better solution to work with either `\stanza` or `\vspace` as parameter for `\pstart`.

Comment: yes, it is better to use `\pstart[\stanta]`. and remember that the paragraph are synchronized.